# Qual o erro neste loop?

Tags: c#, while

Estou querendo baixar um arquivo.exe do meu servidor FTP, mas tem uma parte no código que está me dando trabalho.

Erro: Termo de expressão inválido 'while' (CS1525)

alguém sabe me dizer o que está errado?

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(serverPath));
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            FileStream fs = File.Create(destinationFile + @"\app.exe");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
            int read;
            sr.Read(while ((read = sr.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro é que um `while` não pode ser usado como um parâmetro. Acredito que você queira fazer ao contrário:

```
while (sr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
{
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Seu código está um pouco confuso. Ele não parece fazer o que você quer que ele faça.

Comment: A sua resposta resolveu o problema do while, mas como você disse meu código não faz sentido '-' ele apontou outros erros, você sabe como posso baixar um arquivo.exe do meu servidor FTP? estou a horas procurando uma solução e não encontro.

Comment: @PauloAleixo Não sei se é exatamente isso que você quer, mas antigamente eu usava o [seguinte código](https://gist.github.com/ceifa/48b4d1066dad049338b240f6322784eb) para checar atualizações de software e baixa-las.

Comment: Acho que não, vou dar resolvido pois resolveu o problema com o while.

Answer (score 0):

```
  FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(serverPath));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        FileStream fs = File.Create(destinationFile + @"\app.exe");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = sr.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
```